# BodyParser doesn't recognise input

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

i'm trying to implement a login page using express and body parser, my code is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/database", function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("DB Connection was successful");
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
    password: {type: String, required: true}
});

var user = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

app.set("view engine","jade");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});
console.log('Service has started');

app.post("/menu", function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    var data = {
        name: req.body.name,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    console.log(data);    //I'm trying to display the user received in the login
    res.render("auth");
});
app.listen(8080);
```

The problem is, when I send the info (name and password), the console displays: `{ name: undefined, password: undefined }` But when I use the line `console.log(req)`, the console does show all the request info (which is supposed to be converted into name and password by body-parser).

How do I solve this `undefined` issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you making the request?

Comment: `form(method="post" action="/menu" style="margin-top:1.5em;" enctype="multipart/form-data")
     input(type = "text" name="user" placeholder="usuario" class="form-control")
     input(type="password" name="password" placeholder="contraseña" class="form-control")
     button Login`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse multipart data(`enctype="multipart/form-data"`) using body-parser. You cannot do that. It is written in the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) too. Use [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty) module if you want to parse multipart form data.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using this code

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/database");
var userSchema = {
    name: String,
    pass: Number
};

var User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine","jade");
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.post("/auth",function(req,res){

    console.log(req.bodyParser);
    var data={name:req.body.name,
                pass:req.body.pass};
    console.log(data);
    res.render("index");
});    

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Service started');
```

I still don't know how, but it works.